# C# condition check using try catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have an array of files names.If no file is in the array i need to throw an exception.Can i use try catch .Any one knows please help.Thanks in advance.

```
  string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.csv");.
// throw an exception if no files
  if (fileEntries.Length == 0){}
```

Comment: Catching an exception is the opposite from throwing it. You'd also find many examples if you simply search for 'C# throw an exception'.

Comment: See also: [exceptions and exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/)

Answer (score 4):

> i need to throw an exception.Can i use try catch

The try/catch block is for catching an exception and do something with that information. If you need to throw an exception, simply throw it

```
if (fileEntries.Length == 0)
{
     throw new Exception("No *.csv files available");
}
```

this exception will now be thrown upwards to the method that called a method where this piece of code is situated. Using a try/catch block you can now decide at which level you want to catch this exception and use the information.

Example

```
void method1(){ method2(); }

void method2(){ method3(); }

void method3()
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.csv");.

    if (fileEntries.Length == 0)
    {
         throw new Exception("No *.csv files available");
    }
}
```

if not caught this exception will travel upwards to `method1` and stop your program from execution/abort it drastically. You can catch it at this level and (if for example you have a console application) present the information to the user:

```
void method1()
{
    try
    {
        method2();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

> can i pass an ex obj with exception to add a data for further check

Take a look at the constructor of the basic [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ca3hhw(v=vs.110).aspx) it will allow you to pass a `string` as source of information, or an [additional exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf(v=vs.110).aspx) as inner exception.

**EDIT:**

If you create your own [custom exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions) as suggested by [Corak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336590/corak). You could define your own constructor and pass for example an `enum` for the error code:

```
public enum ErrorCodes
{
    E1,
    E2,
    S4,
    P5
}
public class MyObjectTransferException : Exception
{
    public object ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public MyObjectTransferException(string message, ErrorCodes code) : base(message)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = code;
    }
}
```

Now in `method3` you would throw exactly this type of exception:

```
void method3()
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.csv");.

    if (fileEntries.Length == 0)
    {
         throw new MyObjectTransferException("No *.csv files available", ErrorCodes.E1);
    }
}
```

and in `method1` you would need to catch exactly this type of exception:

```
void method1()
{
    try
    {
        method2();
    }
    catch(MyObjectTransferException ex)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the answer .can i pass an ex obj with exception to add a data for further check?

Comment: @John_Snow Can you elaborate a little bit? It's unclear what you are intending to do.

Comment: i would like to add an error codes to each type exceptions.So if mail server wouild like to pass the value with ex object using ex.data.add("Error",E1)

Comment: @John_Snow you have the means of using a `string` to convey information. See my edit, but you cannot pass an entire object as parameter for the exception.

Comment: @John_Snow - you might want to create [custom exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions). Just keep in mind that whenever you already *have* an exception and want to throw a *new* one, to put the other exception as "inner" exception of the new one.

Comment: @John_Snow I posted an example of how to transmit more than a string. using a custom exception. Have a look. Now you could transmit an enum, or even an entire object is you change the type of `ErrorCodes` to object

Comment: @John_Snow what is `ex.data.add("Error",E1)` supposed to mean? Do you want the exception to store all errors that come up during the program?

Answer (score 0):

Just one example:

```
if (fileEntries.Length == 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("FileNames array must not be empty!");
}
```

You have to decide, what kind of Exception to throw. ArgumentException would be ok if fileEntries was a Parameter to your method ...

**But** : I would like to *recommend NOT to do it this way*. You could return a bool indicating success / failure for example or an error code. Checking that is less expensive than try/catch on the client side. And using exceptions for control flow is generally frowned upon.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225 for more info about that.